# Why is my app crashing? I can't duplicate the error, but received this crash log:

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, crash-log

In my app, I log in to Pocket using the [Pocket API](https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK) but for some users (I can't replicate the error myself) it's crashing the app. I received this crash log:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1ed41496b93fa852b8c

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing it? I can't seem to read what causes the error/crash.

Comment: Please symbolicate the crash report. E.g. by dragging it into the Xcode organizer and you should then see where in your app that happens. (It won't work if you don't have the dSYM of that exact build any more)

Comment: Whenever I drag it into the Xcode organizer, it flashes then doesn't appear in it. So I assume I don't have enough, I just have the .crash file.

Comment: Do you drag it into the "Device Logs" at the top left of the "Devices" tab? (Xcode 4.6.3)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly where.

Comment: There are multiple descriptions available here and on other sites on how to use the symbolication tool manually on the command line instead. You need the app binary and the dSYM that was generated with that exact binary to get that working. Here is  documentation on how to find out if you have those/how to find them: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/about-general-faq/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert of this, but it looks like an exception was raised when you called `compare` on an NSNumber and used the incorrect format. My guess is that you tried to compare a number to something else, possibly a string.